# Volley Error: ParseError on empty requestObject in POST method

Tags: android-volley

I have a dynamic url api for POST method, in which the parameter is some constraint to be attached in url and the request object to be sent is empty i.e. {}.
The response comes fine while using rest client as I am getting complete desired data as expected, but when it comes to making that POST request call from android, Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown.

```
 MyJsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new MyJsonObjectRequest(
                false,
                getActivity(),
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                requestObject,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        Utils.DEBUG(TAG, "RequestBody : " + new Gson().toJson(requestObject));
                        Utils.DEBUG(TAG, "onResponse() called : " + new Gson().toJson(response));
                        String responseString = new Gson().toJson(response);
                        fPOMobileReviewPassData = ParseManager.getInstance().fromJSON(response, FPOMobileReviewPassData.class);
                        airlineId = fPOMobileReviewPassData.getAirlineId();
                        updateUI();

                        if (flagAddUserAPI) {
                            callAddUserApi(loginData);
                        }
                        Utils.hideProgressDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Utils.showVolleyError(error, getActivity());
                Utils.hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }
        );


        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple the server is giving back a `JSONArray` with just one element inside. A `JSONArray` is not a `JSONObject`. That's why the parsing is failing. or vise versa.

Note :first check your response is `JSONArray` `JSONObject` or `sting`

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final String url = "Your_url";

    // prepare the Request
    JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // display response
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );



    // add it to the RequestQueue
    queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: It is giving response as JSONObject form, not JSONArray, in rest client

Comment: so response printing ? log

Comment: control is going in onErrorResponse  and thus printing Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can you provide your test URL

Comment: it is proprietary, cannot share though I can assure the url is functional in ios code as well

Comment: its impossible to check what is exact root cause